# Managing ListView content on Orientation change

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, screen-orientation

I have a retained Fragment in my app that contain a ListView with a sort of gallery. When device is in portrait i must show 2 pictures per row, and when user rotate device i would like to show 3 pictures for row.
How can i handle this orientation change into my custom adapter for obtain this behavior?

Comment: why you have not tried recyclerview?

Comment: most easiest way is to make 2 layouts for your adapter. one for portrait and other one for landscape mode.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are using the latest implementation of Android then you might be using Android Architecture Components.
   Use LiveData, this survives configuration/orientation changes and will resolve your issue.
   For more go through the links below:
   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
   https://github.com/shaz-tech/AndroidArchitectureComponentsDemo
2. If using old implementation of Android the use savedInstanceState.
   See link below:
   http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/

Comment: read the question again :) it's about managing data not saving it's state.

Comment: LiveData manages the data. Please go through their official doc.